# Iterate over java.util.Map with custom objects in Scala

Tags: scala, apache-kafka

I'm new to writing code in Scala. I'm trying to iterate over a java Map with custom objects as key value pairs. Specifically I'm trying to go over the Map of TopicPartitions and OffSetMetadata Map when committing offsets to Kafka.

Here is the code that i have written

```
override def onComplete(map: util.Map[TopicPartition, OffsetAndMetadata], e: Exception): Unit = {
  val sb = new StringBuffer()
  map.forEach((partition:TopicPartition ,offsets : OffsetAndMetadata) => {
    sb.append(partition.topic()+","+partition.partition()+","+offsets.offset()+"\n")
  })
```

However I get a compilation error saying

**error: type mismatch;
 found   : (org.apache.kafka.common.TopicPartition, org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.OffsetAndMetadata) => StringBuffer
[ERROR]  required: java.util.function.BiConsumer[_ >: org.apache.kafka.common.TopicPartition, _ >: org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.OffsetAndMetadata]
[ERROR]       map.forEach((partition:TopicPartition ,offsets : OffsetAndMetadata) => {
[ERROR]            ^**

It indicates the => operator while pointing the error, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Seems to work [here](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/MwlWLCTOTqmiY6M747Lp2g) (with maps of other classes). Could you make a complete example which reproduces the error?

Comment: Why don't you try [converting](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/conversions-between-java-and-scala-collections.html) the map from Java to Scala first?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best bet I have is that you use Scala 2.11 that is still not really aware of Java 8 and functional interfaces. That's why the compiler can't automatically convert your Scala lambda to a matching `BiConsumer`. According to my understanding the simplest workaround is to create a `BiConsumer` explicitly as in

```
override def onComplete(map: util.Map[TopicPartition, OffsetAndMetadata], e: Exception): Unit = {
  val sb = new StringBuffer()
  map.forEach(new java.util.function.BiConsumer[TopicPartition, OffSetMetadata]() {
    def accept(partition: TopicPartition, offsets: OffSetMetadata ) = {
      sb.append(partition.topic() + "," + partition.partition() + "," + offsets.offset() + "\n")
    }
  })
}
```

Well the other work-around is to wrap Java-`Map` into a Scala-`Map` first and use Scala interface. And of course you can upgrade to Scala 2.12 where this conversion of lambda to `BiConsumer` is done by the compiler.

Comment: You are right, I am indeed using Scala 2.11 , this worked! Thanks for the help!